# Unable to create static library for .c files. Getting src/crc16.c:35:10: fatal error: defs.h: No such file or directory error

Tags: c++, c, linux, makefile, static-libraries

1.unable to make of this code

2. unable to create test static library

```
    //thi is target in my make file
    PROGRAM = test.a

    current_dir = $(shell pwd)

    #INCLUDEDIRS = inc/

    C_INCLUDE_PATH = inc/
    LIBDIRS = -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

    LIBS = -lpthread -lrt 

    //adding all the source files
    CXXSOURCES += src/crc16.c
    CXXSOURCES += src/main.c
    CXXSOURCES += src/master.c
    CXXSOURCES += src/user.c

    CXXOBJECTS = $(CXXSOURCES:.c=.o)
    CXXFLAGS = -Wall -pthread -Wmissing-braces -Wmissing-declarations -Wunused-variable -Wunused- 
   but-set-variable $(INCLUDEDIRS)
    CXX = gcc

    LDFLAGS = -lrt -lpthread
    #LDFLAGS = -Llib/ -lrt -lpthread -lmicrohttpd -ljson-c 

    all: $(PROGRAM)

    #
    # Link target: automatically builds its object dependencies before
    # executing its link command.
    #
here adding creating object files

    $(PROGRAM): $(CXXOBJECTS) 
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@  $(CXXOBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS)

    crc16.o: crc16.c defs.h
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o crc16.o defs.h crc16.c 

    main.o: main.c defs.h
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o main.o main.c  

    master.o: master.c defs.h
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o master.o master.c

    user.o: user.c defs.h
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o user.o user.c
```

generating the target

```
    test.a: crc16.o main.o master.o user.o

    #
    # Clean target: "make -f Makefile.Linux clean" to remove unwanted objects and executables.
    #

//for make clean
    clean:
        $(RM) -f src/*.o $(PROGRAM)
```

output:

```
plugin$ make
cc    -c -o src/crc16.o src/crc16.c
src/crc16.c:35:10: fatal error: defs.h: No such file or directory
   35 | #include "defs.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: src/crc16.o] Error 1
```

Comment: »»mbdefs.h: No such file «« : Looks like an mbdyn or freemodbus header ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You get a message about `defs.h`. First step is: Check if this file is available on your machine. Second step: Add the correct path to your as include folder to your compiler command.

Comment: Unless you are explicitely mixing C and C++, please only tag the relevant language.

Comment: Is mbdefs.h in the include path you've defined: `C_INCLUDE_PATH = inc/` ?